# Error when calling the method addHTML using jsPDF with html2canvas

Tags: jquery, pdf, jspdf, html2canvas

I have a web application and I am trying to use jsPDF and html2canvas to generate the PDF file.

```
function imprimirPDF() {
    var pdf = new jsPDF();
    html2canvas($('#information').html()).then(function (canvas) {
        pdf.addHTML(canvas, {pagesplit: true, retina: true}, function () {
            var fileName = 'Informe ' + $('#reportType option:selected').text() + ' ' +
                $('#curso option:selected').text();

            if ($scope.filterAlumni !=null)
                fileName+=' ' + $('#filterAlumni option:selected').text();

            pdf.save(fileName + '.pdf');
        });
    })
}
```

The name of the is generated based on some selects and the error that I am receiving is

```
Uncaught (in promise) Proxy must be used when rendering url
```